# Moving comments to chat

Tags: discussion

I would like to have a discussion about the practice of "moving comments to chat".

I understand that it is a useful tool which can be used to promote the "purity" of the SE Q&A format, however as this function is currently implemented, it effectively kills all discussion about the Answer and, in many cases, removes valuable contextualization or critique of the answer. The difference between simply deleting all the comments and moving them to chat is minute.

Here are my primary reasons I think the practice should be used only in absolutely extreme outlier cases:

**Comments are important**

Comments, like posts, have the ability to be voted on. It occasionally happens that a comment receives more upvotes than the post itself, which usually indicates that there is severe need for revision of the answer (or some aspect of it). This is vitally important, and should be immediately visible on the same page as the Answer post. Banishing comments to chat not only removes all valuation of those comments (there are no upvotes in chat that I can see) and it makes them a click away, which is basically gone.

**There's no appeal process**

Many of the actions on SE are tied to user reputation, including features like editing other people's posts or other "moderator"-esque actions--this is a very unique and "strange" feature that I quite like about SE. Despite this, the ability to move comments to chat seems to be a function reserved for moderators with no appeal or voting process, as closing a post would be. As far as I can tell, there's no way for regular high-reputation users to, for example, bring back a highly-upvoted comment so that it sits underneath the post, short of editing the post to include the comment (which I think we can all agree upon is a bad idea).

**Comments are fun**

This is maybe a bit of "realpolitik", but fun, stimulating, and occasionally adversarial exchanges in the comments are one of the primary reasons I engage with the site. I suspect others feel the same (?) and banishing comment discussions to chat makes me less likely to engage with the site and ask/answer questions. I feel that, if the price for raising engagement, reach, and quality of answers is a tiny bit of "chaos" in the comments, that's a sacrifice that we should be willing to make.

---

Obviously, there is a personal connection, because this post was motivated by is a recent usage of this tool in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/65245/21538) by moderator [@Rory Alsop](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/38/rory-alsop) where my comment was "deleted". As I remember--because I can't look it up anymore as there are no comment vote values visible in the chat--one of my comments had like four upvotes, which, in comparison to a post which itself has about 10 upvotes, would indicate to me that the general active userbase either agreed with my point or thought it was a valuable contribution or "post-it note" to the Answer, in alignment with the rules outlining comments ([explained here](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)).

While I'd prefer if this tool were never or nearly never used, I can see a compromise solution where perhaps only comments that have zero upvotes are banished to the chat-realm.

Thoughts, feelings, opinions?

Comment: Comments get deleted because they're clutter and have soon served their purpose or should not have been written. Chat gets preserved and is the appropriate venue for discussion and "fun" as you say. Why would one desire a site policy that says *do not use the very deliberate functionality built into all sites, in favour of treating SE like yet another free-for-all forum*?

Comment: I agree with most of what you've said. I think it might be a good idea to copy and paste some of the comments into an answer so that they do not get lost - especially when the comments are used as answers or to correct misinformation in answers. But my preference would be just to have the comments remain forever. The site already tries to hide some of them so that they don't clutter up the page - but you can always click on "show N more comments".

Answer (score 5):

While I agree comments are important where they help a post owner to improve their post, they are temporary by definition on Stack Exchange. You may like them, and hey, I like the odd fun comment as well, but not long term. Mods occasionally leave a very highly upvoted comment for longer, but the aim is to delete comments or move them out of the way so people can see the answers. They are not supposed to be valuable other than that ephemeral time period where they can help suggest edits.

Where there are more than 20 comments the system itself prompts to move them to chat, because they significantly impact readability of the questions. They are not deleted - so you have not lost any access to those comments.

In this case I had 2 flags to move comments to chat because there were so many.

Also, moving comments to chat is not a mod-only action.

Comment: I don't hang out on other sites enough to feel sure of this, but maybe we're actually a little lax about having comments moved/deleted here (in part because this site is relatively quiet?), so we get used to them sticking around forever and get surprised when they don't

Comment: @ErinAnne Yes, we have historically been pretty lax compared to some other sites.